# Can't edit file copied in different folder with [System.IO.File]::Copy

Tags: .net, powershell

I am using Powershell v3.0 to do different operations on files, and there's a scenario that is making me puzzled.

I have 2 folders:
C:\Tmp1
C:\Tmp2

In Folder C:\Tmp1, I have a file MyFile1.csv. I open this file manually with Notepad++, hit Enter, hit backspace, save the file. Everything's fine.

I run the following script which will make a copy of the original file from Tmp1 to Tmp2:

```
set-location -Path C:\Tmp1
$FileOld = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile1.csv"
set-location -Path C:\Tmp2
$FileNew = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile1.csv"

[System.IO.File]::Copy($FileOld, $FileNew)
[System.IO.File]::Close
```

I then open the C:\Tmp2\MyFile1.csv using notepad++, Enter, Backspace, Save, and I get a message telling me to make sure the file is not opened with another program. therefore I can't amend this copy of the file as I can't save it. I have tried even after closing powershell ise. I can however delete the file.

Now, if I copy the original file into a different file within the same original folder using the following script:

```
set-location -Path C:\Tmp1
$FileOld = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile1.csv"
$FileNew = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile2.csv"

[System.IO.File]::Copy($FileOld, $FileNew)
[System.IO.File]::Close
```

I can then edit MyFile2.csv with Notepad++, Enter, Backspace, Save, and it saves the file fine.

Why can I not copy and edit a file that was copied from one folder to another using [System.Io.File]::Copy?

How can I fix this as I don't want to manipulate the original file inside the original folder?

**EDIT**: I have tried with the powershell command Copy-Item $FileOld $FileNew and I get the same problem. So it is not linked to the [System.IO.File]:: Copy method. But my questions stands nevertheless.

**EDIT 2**: I have found a workaround by running the following script:

```
set-location -Path C:\Tmp1
$FileOld = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile1.csv"
$FileNew = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile2.csv"
Copy-Item $FileOld $FileNew

set-location -Path C:\Tmp2
$FileAgn = (Get-Location).Path + "\MyFile1.csv"
Move-Item $FileNew $FileAgn
```

With this script I can Open with Notepad++, Enter, Backspace, Save, without any problem.

Any type of copy into a different folder doesn't seem to be releasing the new copied file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like permission problems more than anything else (which may be copied by `Copy-Item` and not by `::Copy`, or something like that) - since the file cannot be open once the ISE was closed. The powershell process cannot hold the file open after it's closed (except for some case - see below), so I doubt this is the actual problem.

Furthermore, I managed once in my previous job to create a folder in which I didn't have any permission to edit files, but I could delete them freely - which sounds exactly like your case.

1. To make sure powershell is not actually holding the file somehow, make sure that after you exited powershell and/or the ISE, none of them appear to be running in the task manager. Specifically, make sure that there aren't any processes that were started by your script and given a pointer to this file and are still running
2. Check the actual file permissions (right click on the file, go to properties) and make sure that you have the Write/Modify flags set for your user (either directly or via group permissions). Also make sure the file doesn't have the read-only flag set
3. Back again from powershell, try using `File::OpenWrite` on the file and see the exception you are getting - this would be more detailed than the one provided by Notepad++

Comment: The correct answer is 2. It was a file permission issue. I was opening ISE and saving ps1 files as Administrator. And the file I was generating was inheriting these permissions. Even though I am part of the Administrators group, I still was not allowed to edit the resulting file. So I changed the permissions on my ps1 script, and when it generates a file, the file inherits the permissions from the ps1 file. I did go into the properties of the file at some point, but when I saw Administrators as part of the permissions I thought I automatically have the same permissions. I was wrong. Thanks!